# Custom Foreign Key Property

Tags: python, django, django-models, properties, django-forms

I have a model called `Personnel` which I'm using as the profile model for the `User` model. Here's my model

```
class Personnel(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User
    )
    phone = models.CharField(
        null=False, max_length=50, verbose_name="Phone"
    )
```

I need to use the above model in with a ModelForm. Here's my `ModelForm`:

```
class PersonnelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Personnel
        exclude = ('user')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        personnel = Personnel(user=User.objects.create(username=(''.join(choice(ascii_uppercase + digits) for x in range(30)))))
        super(PersonnelForm, self).__init__(
             instance=personnel, *args, **kwargs
        )
```

I dont need the `user` field to be displayed on the web from so I'm excluding it. However I still need to pass a value for it so initiate my `PersonnelForm` by passing it a `Personnel` instance. The `User` mode has a field called `email` which should be input by the user but I cant display this field as it not a field on my `Personnel` model.

Can I create a virtual field called `email` which when set, sets the value of the `user.email` field and when get, gets the value of the same. Something like so:

```
@property
def email():
    def fget(self):
        return 'fff'

    def fset(self, email):
        self.user.email = email
```

I need to it in some manner similar to the above snippet because I''l be using the `PersonnelForm` with [Django's generic CRUD views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/generic-views/?from=olddocs#create-update-delete-generic-views).

Thanks.

(Please feel free to edit and suggest a better name for the title so it may benefit others as well.)

---

Using Daniel's advice:

```
class PersonnelForm(forms.ModelForm):

    email = forms.EmailField(
        required=True, label=_("Email")
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Personnel
        exclude = ('user')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        commit = kwargs.get('commit', True)
        kwargs['commit'] = False
        personnel = super(PersonnelForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        if not personnel.user: #To prevent creating a new user when updating.
            user = User.objects.create_user(
                email=self.cleaned_data['email'],
                username=(''.join(choice(ascii_uppercase + digits) for x in range(30))),
            )
        if commit:
            personnel.save()
        return personnel
```

This works well for creating anew record using the ModelForm but I can't seem to update the email or view the email when I'm updating.

Comment: You shouldn't need to pass in any values for user since you've excluded the property from the PersonnelForm.

Comment: Brandon, if I don't exclude the user field then it gives me a drop down list in my form for which to create the `Personnel` record. I need to create a `Personnel` record and automatically create a `User`  behind the scenes. Each `User record` will have a random `username`, the `password` is nullable and I'll deal with it later but I need the user to be able to specify the email address — thereby the property mess.

Comment: I completely understand. You can create the User object and set whatever properties without the property mess. There are at least 3 places you can create the User object - in the save method of the Personnel object, the view that handles the Personnel form, or even in a post_save signal attached to the Personnel class.

Comment: I cant edit the view as it one of Django's inbuilt generic views. I need to accept input from the user for the email address field but this won't show up until I've added that field to my Model. If you look at my code, I'm already creating the `User` and passing that in an instance to the ModelForm. I don't need the user to input the username as it is a randomly generated but the `email` does need to be input. I don't see how a `post_save` signal would help me if I don't have the email and the same goes for custom `save` method. Forgive me if I missing something here and sounding dumb.

Comment: No worries. You can always add a field to a model form that doesn't correspond to a field on the model, like the email field you need on the Personnel form. You could take that value and apply it to your User object.

Answer (score 1):

There are two misconceptions in your question. Firstly, that you need to pass a value for the field even though you've excluded it; and secondly, that you can't include a field that's not on the model. Neither of these are true.

It's definitely possible to define a separate `email` field, display it on the form along with the real model fields, and then later use that value to create the `User` object.

Given that you don't want to modify the view to do this logic (which IMO is the wrong decision, but it's your code), you could do this in an overridden `save` method:

```
class PersonnelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = Personnel
        exclude = ('user',)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # call super method with commit=False, but remember original commit arg
        commit = kwargs.get('commit', True)
        kwargs['commit'] = False
        new_object = super(PersonnelForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        user = User.objects.create_user(
            email=self.cleaned_data['user'],
            username=get_random_username(),
            password=User.objects.make_random_password()
        )
        new_object.user = user
        # now save if commit was not explicitly set to False
        if commit:
            new_object.save()
        return new_object
```

Comment: Cheers Daniel. That did it. I was under the impression that you can't have additional fields in ModelForm but it seems that you can.

Comment: I ran into a little glitch. You see, your method seems to work when I'm creating a new record but when I'm updating that record using the ModelForm it tries creating a new `User`. In order to work around this I added a simple `if` clause. (See edit). The other issue that I'm currently unable to solve is how to display the value of the `personnel.user.email` field when I'm updating. All the fields get updated direct from the `Personnel` record but the `email` is in the `User` model.